# JMSTemplate with multiple brokers. Destination resolving exception

Tags: jms, messaging, spring-jms, jms-topic, jmstemplate

I have problem which I am trying solve all day, without success... 
I have an application which trying to send/receive messages to/from external system A and external system B. A and B it is WLS based external systems.

While my application is coming up - i am reading all configurations and building my applicational JMSProducer and injecting JMSTemlate with predefined destination name in it.

Here is my code:

```
private JMSProducer initProducer(Conf conf) {
    DestinationResolver destinationResolver = getDestinationResolver(conf);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = getConnectionFactory();
    String destinationName = conf.getDestinationName();
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(destinationName);
    return new JMSProducer(jmsTemplate);
}

public DestinationResolver getDestinationResolver(Conf conf) {
    JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    destinationResolver.setCache(false);
    destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(getJNDITemplate(conf));
    return destinationResolver;
}

private JndiTemplate getJNDITemplate(Conf conf) {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String connectionFactoryClassName = externalSystemConf.getConnectionParam().getConnectionFactory();
    properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", connectionFactoryClassName);
    properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", getProviderURL(conf.getConnectionParam()));
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(properties);
    return jndiTemplate;
}
```

Now scenario what happens.

My app is up and running, external system A with 2 queues and external system B with 1 queue also is up and running.

1. I am retrieving relevant, already initialized JMSProducer in which I have already injected JMSTemplate with destinationName.
2. Sending messages to queues of external system A
3. Again retrieving next instance of JMSProducer relevant for system B
4. Sending messages to queue of external system B
5. At this stage everything is good, all messages delivered to relevant queues in external systems.
6. Now I am getting again JMSProducer which relevant for external system A, and trying to send messages to one of the queues. And in this stage I have a problem, DestinationResolutionException is thrown:

Destination [topic2.queueName] not found in JNDI

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'topic2.queueName' didn't find subcontext 'topic2'. Resolved ""

How it is possible, I have just sent messages to external system A with the same destination and  it worked fine. Why it throwing exception when I am sending message to A after I tried to sent it to B?

By the way, If I will try to change cache flag to true when defining destination resolver, it is solving this problem.  However in this case I starting to have problem when my external system is going to be restarted. After restart it also have some exception related to destination resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Problem was that in both external systems, in WLS - domain name, jms server name, and jms module name were the same. And weblogic client stores state, map with this names.

This is from WLS documentation

> **Interoperating WebLogic Server domains have the following
>   restrictions:**
>
> Domain names must be unique.
>
> WebLogic server names must be unique, even if they are in two
>   different domains.
>
> JMS server names must be unique, even if they are in two different
>   domains.
>
> Interoperating domains may have special Security considerations.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13738/best_practice.htm#JMSAD635

After changing all above mentioned names - problem was solved.